# Uppercase characters in SOAP request element

Tags: .net, soap, asmx

I'm adding functionality to an existing asmx web service.
Everything works as expected except in one scenario. In one request, I mistakenly capitalised a letter in an element name.  See markup below; instead of "Postcode", I put in "PostCode"

```
<Sites>
    <Site>
        <ID>123456</ID>
        <Name>123 Road Street</Name>
        <Status>Approved</Status>
        <PostCode>SW12R 55R</PostCode>            
    </Site>
</Sites>
```

The error message I got back from the service indicated an invalid or missing field, but the only difference is that capital C. If I use "Postcode", or "postcode", the request goes through without an issue.

Is this a peculiarity of ASMX web services, or something common to SOAP web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on service behavior and what's in the server side code.
But in general that is a expected behavior considering **`XML Tags are Case Sensitive`**. 
[Here is more detail on it](http://xml.silmaril.ie/case.html)

Comment: Cheers for that. This seems the likely answer, so I'll mark this as the answer.  I suspect it also has to do with fields in markup  mapping to the properties in the .NET objects they're deserialized to.